# How to identify Treck TCP/IP library usage in a PC?

Tags: zero-day

I was informed recently about the RIPPLE20 vulnerabilities.

Can I identify the usage of a specific protocol on my PC or inside some application on a PC?

I think that the first thing to do in these cases is to find the assets that can be influenced by these zero days.
In that case, I think that the identification of the specific protocol used can be a good start.

Comment: Treck is not used in a PC. The PC Operating System has its own TCP/IP stack. Applications in a PC don't use their own stack. Please look up what RIPPLE20 is and what it affects.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to see egress and ingress network traffic for a given computer, you can install Wireshark and inspect the individual packets that are carried by a NIC. This can allow you to identify the given networking protocols in use on your computer. If you want to see all connections that are allowed on your PC you would also have to check the firewall settings for your machine (Advanced Firewall settings on Windows, nftables or iptables on GNU\Linux as two examples).

However, as you question regarding protocol identification is in regards to a vulnerable software package [used for embedded systems](https://treck.com/treck-ipv4v6-dual-stack-datasheet/) it is close to certain you won't find anything on your PC. Despite this, the vulnerability may affect you as the list of affected devices as reported by [ZDnet is pretty large](https://www.zdnet.com/article/ripple20-vulnerabilities-will-haunt-the-iot-landscape-for-years-to-come/) (including routers and IoT devices). Contacting your manufacturer* and ensuring all firmware is kept up to date is likely your best bet to manage the risk.

I do not believe you could readily determine at-risk systems by checking network traffic for TCP/IP, as this is a hugely prevalent standard that pretty much everything will use. In addition determining the TCP/IP *stack* that a device is using would be easier to discover by administering the devices in question and determining all hardare/software loaded if possible.

*Manufacturers may not be able to provide any information regarding vulnerability, as mentioned in the ZDnet article.

Comment: The whole first section about wireshark is completely unrelated to the question

Comment: hello, it was added due to this line from the OP: Can I identify the usage of a specific protocol on my PC or inside some application on a PC? It seemed to me they were asking as a generalization for future reference, hence the mention of wireshark.